# "To increase competitiveness in" or "to increase competitiveness on"?

Tags: vocabulary, prepositions, expressions

Which phrase is the correct one?

> to increase competitiveness *in* the EU labor market
>   to increase competitiveness *on* the EU labor market

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In is correct.

'On' in terms of a market means something for sale. You put your house 'on the market'.

Answer (score 1):

English is not my forte. But here is my two cents.  **IN** is correct since competitiveness is an event that must occur *in* a population.  In this case the population is **the EU labor market**

Change the word *competitiveness* to *murderousness* and it will be clearer.  :)